# Why does this C++ constructor automatically direct to the copy constructor?

Tags: c++

I am getting

```
Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
Error    C2280    'World::World(const World &)': attempting to reference a
deleted function
```

as error (because there is no copy constructor in my class) at the line of calling

```
World wd = World(&vp, am);
```

which is a constructor.

I am very confused about why a copy constructor would be directed to automatically.

Does anyone have any idea?

Here is my class header:

```
class World{
    public:
        KDtree tree;
        ViewPlane *vp;
        DrawPanel * paintArea = &(DrawPanel(wxString("test"), wxDefaultPosition, 400,400));
        wxApp app;
        Vector3d backGround;
        vector <Geometry*> objects;
        Shader shader;
        vector<Light*>lights;

        World(ViewPlane*, Vector3d& Am);
        ....
}
```

And my constructor:

```
World::World(ViewPlane * v, Vector3d &Ambient){
    vp = v;
    shader = (Shader(Ambient));
}
```

Comment: You probably want to write `World wd{&vp, am};` instead.

Comment: because when you do this `shader = (Shader(Ambient))` you are invoking the copy constructor. It's how C++ compilers interpret that syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Using the

```
Bar b = Bar(...)
```

syntax does actually do copy initialisation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization

You probably want just

```
World wd(&vp, am);
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers, I'd like to note that since C++17 due to guaranteed copy elision no copy from a temporary object `T()` is involved in the expression like `T t = T()`. An existing and accessible copy constructor is not needed.

Comment: And of course one could already use `auto&& b = …` since C++11 to avoid the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Up until C++17

```
World wd = World(&vp, am);
```

is interpreted as "construct a `World` object with the expression `World(&vp, am)`, then use that object to copy construct local variable `World wd`. Most compilers will elide the copy step, but are still required by the standard to require the copy constructor they won't call.

In C++17, compilers are required to elide the copy, and are therefore able to compile this code fragment even if there is no copy constructor.
So your options are either to use C++17, or use the syntax

```
World wd{&vp, am};
```

(Parentheses in place of the curly braces would also be fine.)

Comment: (This is really just combining two other answers into one, for a more complete answer to the question.)